# Apply algebraic methods in solving problems? help i have test on wednesday...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

A teacher has hired a school bus for $560 for a day trip with students.
The cost of hiring the bus is to be shared equally between the students.
At the last moment, three of the students were unable to go.
As a result, the cost to each of those who did go was increased by 1.50.
How many students finally went on the trip?
Justify your answer.

I thought that the working would be (560/(x-3))-(560/x) = $1.50. Apparently, it's (560/x)-(560/(x-3)) = 1.5 which is completely different. Why is it (560/x)-(560/(x-3))?

Comment: Your proposal is the good one, because $560/(x-3) > 560/x$

Comment: Consider that the fact that you have a test on Wednesday or on Friday has nothing to do here.

Comment: thanks for the first comment, but didn't need the second comment though. Just asking for help.

Comment: Please change the title. It should not contain that you have a test on Wednesday.

Comment: $x$ is the number of students who went on the trip, not the total number of students. The solution should be $(560/x)-(560/(x+3))=1.50$

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested equation is correct. In contrast, the equation

$$\frac{560}{x}-\frac{560}{x-3}=1.5$$

imputes a non-real number of students $x$, which is only possible if the students astral travel.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm guessing my math test wouldn't be hideous enough for it to include astral travelling